# How do I insert "and" into a working code?

Tags: syntax-error

I need to write a pine script code {add on to existing code} alert for when the DEMA and the TEMA BOTH have crossed above price and when both have crossed below price. I don't want the alert to go off if only one of these DEMA or TEMA crosses,I only want alert to happen when both cross either above price or below price.

The way I have it now it only alerts when one of them crosses ,not both. Here's my code. PS: I tried chatGPt and that screwed everything up,it never finishes writing the script. Thanks for your time.

I tried adding "and" but  I'm always getting error messages. I hope to get a fix here,please.

```
// Entries and Exits
longCondition = crossover(close, tema)
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("TEMA Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(close, tema)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("TEMA Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

strategy.exit("TEMA Long Entry Id", "My Long Exit Id", stop=lowest(low, 10))
strategy.exit("TEMA Short Entry Id", "My Short Exit Id", stop=highest(high, 10))

// Entries and Exits
longConditionDEMA = crossover(close, dema)
if (longConditionDEMA)
    strategy.entry("DEMA Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortConditionDEMA = crossunder(close, dema)
if (shortConditionDEMA)
    strategy.entry("DEMA Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

strategy.exit("DEMA Long Entry Id", "DEMA Long Exit Id", stop=lowest(low, 10))
strategy.exit("DEMA Short Entry Id", "DEMA Short Exit Id", stop=highest(high, 10))
```

Comment: I tried adding the actual pine script I'm working on but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Thanks for the link on how to post the code. I just posted the code and entered it in my first post,hopefully someone can help me,thanks again.